# Async doesn't appear to run concurrently

Tags: kotlin

The following code uses 2 async function calls:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import kotlin.system.*

fun main() = runBlocking<Unit> {
    val time = measureTimeMillis {
        val one = async { doSomethingUsefulOne() }
        val two = async { doSomethingUsefulTwo() }
        println("The answer is ${one.await() + two.await()}")
    }
    println("Completed in $time ms")    
}

suspend fun doSomethingUsefulOne(): Int {

    delay(3000L) // pretend we are doing something useful here
    println("first")
    return 13
}

suspend fun doSomethingUsefulTwo(): Int {

    delay(1000L) // pretend we are doing something useful here, too
    println("second")
    return 29
}
```

The println results in "first" being printed first followed by "second". But according to the docs, these asyncs should be running concurrently. But since the first one has a delay of 3 seconds, why is its println running first? In fact, it doesn't even matter if I put the println before or after the delay. I get the same result.

Comment: On my system it behaves as one would expect. `second` is printed before `first`. Finally printed `The answer is 42` and `Completed in 3022 ms`. Are you really sure that your observations belong to the code shown?

Comment: You can try the code online [here](https://pl.kotl.in/HhUfvrQUX)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you have a gap between the 2 functions is the way you have called them in your print line:

```
println("The answer is ${one.await() + two.await()}")
```

Try changing .await() to .launch().
Await() calls the function and then stops until it is complete.